# Is there a way to create a simple Command Line-based text editor such as Nano using Python?

Tags: python, text-editor, command-line-tool

I was tasked with creating a command line text editor in just two weeks by my friend, and I think it would actually be pretty fun to do. I'm aloud to use any resources available, I just have to complete it by the deadline, which is why I'm here. What I'm going for is reading the contents of the file the user specifies and then printing them line by line, and then making them editable. Is there any way to do this? If so, could you show me how? P.S. I'm on Mac.

Comment: yes there definitely is.

Comment: ok, but how can i do it?

Comment: You code it with python

Comment: yes, but could you show me the code to do it?

Comment: To me, this seems harder than making a GUI editor. I would start with [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) module documentation

Comment: i've already dabbled in java, c++ and c#, but none of them really worked for me. anyways, thanks! i'll check out curses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I've never tried**, but I believe it's entirely possible.

Try starting with those libraries:

- https://github.com/willmcgugan/rich
- https://github.com/urwid/urwid
- https://github.com/jquast/blessed